# Custom data attribute "data-watch" has a strange behaviour in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, custom-data-attribute

I was making a relatively flexible system requiring given form fields to be listened on their `onchange` event and decided to specify which elements should be listened to in the HTML via a custom data attribute containing a CSS selector pointing to said elements. I decided to name this attribute `data-watch`.

As I am developping in Chromium, everything was going fine, but when i tested my work in Firefox, it wasn't anymore. I noticed that it was showing a strange behaviour, as other custom data attributes were handled just fine, the one named `data-watch` was somehow handled differently:

The value returned by calling `myElement.dataset` was as follows (test on the `about:blank` page):

- Chrome --> `DOMStringMap {custom: "blabla", watch: "myField"}`
- Firefox --> `DOMStringMap {custom: "blabla", watch: function ()}`

So to me, it would seem that Firefox give special treatment to the attribute named `data-watch`. Consequently, my question is first whether I seem to be right about my assumptions, and if so, whether there is a good reason for Firefox to do that (and if so, why aren't other browsers doing the same ?) or if it is a bug, as, to my understanding, the custom data attributes should be left entirely to the developpers.

Here's a snippet I made so you can visualize the problem easily. As you can see, the real lies with its consequences, as the dataset built by JQuery is incomplete because of Firefox's behaviour.

```js
var vanilla = document.querySelector('#myDiv').dataset;
console.log("Vanilla: ", vanilla);


var jquery = $('#myDiv').data();
console.log("JQuery: ", jquery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="myDiv" data-custom="blabla" data-watch="myField"></div>

Check your console.
```

Comment: It's a known _issue_ because in FF watch is a function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch). Note that if (sigh) you delete watch function from object prototype it'll work again.

Comment: Thanks, i had no idea about this function. Now the question is: why is this function bound to the custom attribute ?

Comment: Answer is more easy: what you see in console?

Comment: As I wrote before, Firefox seems to act as if it's a function, except when trying to evaluate it as a function, Firefox says that's it's not. Pretty weird, in my opinion.